# Find keywords in multiple pptx files

Tags: python, powerpoint

I need to extract the page number and name of the pptx files containing a keyword. I am able to do so with 1 pptx and have tried a few things but nothing seems to work. I add my code here

```
prs = Presentation('Informe Final.pptx')

print('Documento: '+ files[0].replace('.pptx',''))
slides = prs.slides
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_text_frame:
            continue
        for p in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
            for run in p.runs:
                if 'driver' in run.text.lower():
                    print('Diapositiva numero ' + str(slides.index(slide)+1))
```

Comment: I guess that we are missing how you populate the `files` list, and how you iterate it... Then, the first step in that loop would be to create a new `prs` object with `files[counter]`

Comment: sounds like a good aproach, I will try making a list of the files and iterate it

Comment: @xverges I actually did it with a list and a counter and it worked. you are awesome :)